# Blender material button not working

Tags: materials

Blender material button doesn't work for selected object.
[image]

As you can see, it worked on the first object, but wont work for the plane, either. Maybe I messed up at the first object"s material, cause I'm new and it just wants me to give up?
I tried transparency to the first object and I assume that we wouldn't be able to see that without rendering, since it's not partially transparent in this view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In the screenshot it looks to me that you have to scroll up in the material window to view the contents, which for some reason is a bit higher up than what is currently shown.

Comment: That's it. I couldn't find "diffuse bdfs" (or whatever), either, in the other object's material. but now, it's right there too. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved the problem.